# Wordpress File Upload Error — File Size or Timeout?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, file-upload

I get an http error while trying to upload large files to Wordpress. I've edited the php.ini and .htaccess files to updated the file size and time limits. This is somewhat new territory for me. Am I missing something?

php.ini

```
post_max_size=90M
upload_max_filesize=90M
memory_limit=90M

max_execution_time=3600
```

.htaccess

```
php_value post_max_size 90M
php_value upload_max_filesize 90M
php_value memory_limit 90M
php_value max_execution_time 3600
php_value max_input_time 3600
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600
```

Comment: did you restart your server ?

Comment: I am on shared hosting. I was told to just save the php.ini file and it would update immediately. Because it is shared hosting, I don't believe I would even have access to restart the server.

Comment: https://themeskills.com/fix-http-error-when-uploading-images-to-wordpress/

Comment: Great, thanks! I added `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '90M');` to the wp-config file and it seems to have solved the issue. Thanks a ton! Create an answer and I'll mark it as solved. @vrajesh

Comment: @MatthewS I am glad it works for you :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Add WP_MEMORY_LIMIT into your wp-config.php file.

This setting may not work if your host does not allow you to increase the PHP memory limit.

In **wp-config.php**

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M')
```